# Как называется такой приём в русском языке?

Tags: правила

Не многие знают, **а я на своём канале буду раскрывать тайны**, Венера единственная планета Солнечной системы, вращающаяся против часовой стрелки.

Как называется приём с добавлением в предложение того, что я выделил жирным?

Comment: Вставные конструкции https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/vstavnye-konstruktsii.html

Comment: @user190920  Не хотите ответить "легитимно"? И ссылка уже есть.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец написал ответ и пометил его [как общий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2436/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (так как это не я догадался про вставные конструкции, а `@user190920`)

Answer (score 0):

> Замечание от написавшего этот ответ: этот ответ частично взят из комментария @user190920, поэтому был сделан общим.

Это называется *вставные конструкции*. Они нужны для добавления в предложение замечаний от автора или добавления какой-то дополнительной информации. В данном случае это конструкция нужна и для того, и для другого.

Вставные конструкции очень легко узнать: ведь если их убрать, то главный смысл предложения не поменяется:

- Со вставной конструкцией:

> Не многие знают, а я на своём канале буду раскрывать тайны, Венера - единственная планета Солнечной системы, вращающаяся против часовой стрелки.

- Без:

> Не многие знают, что Венера - единственная планета Солнечной системы, вращающаяся против часовой стрелки.

Ещё стоит сказать, что вставные конструкции либо помещаются в скобки, либо обособляются запятыми или тире. [Пример](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473648/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5).

[Статья на эту тему](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/vstavnye-konstruktsii.html)

**P.S.** У вас в предложении было пропущено тире (между словами Венера  и единственная).

Comment: Зонтик, всё хорошо (правда, есть опечатка, и ещё кое-что я бы подправил), но вот запятые для выделения вставки в данном случае, по-моему, далеко не лучший вариант, да и в этом источнике о запятых ни слова.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец про запятые в вопросе ничего не сказано (кстати, запятые в вопросе  верно расставлены). Вопрос был про то, как приём называется.

Comment: Отвечая на заданный вопрос, думаю, нужно обращать внимание и на побочные моменты (Вы же ведь указали на отстуствующее тире), и на сопутствующие – те, которые непосредственно связаны с темой. Запятые, может, и допустимы, но менее информативны, что ли, графически плохо подчёркивают нужный смысл. Тем более что в [правилах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123) (Розенталь) сказано: "Вставные конструкции... выделяются **скобками** или **тире**".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец дополнил ответ